# Where do I put the global-bundle.pem file in a typescript lambda directory generated using SAM CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli, aws-documentdb

I have been manually building and uploading a zip of my lambda function to AWS until I recently discovered SAM CLI - the way better way to develop lambdas locally.

My problem is that my lambda connects to DocDB, so it needs a global-bundle.pem file for TLS. In my old cobbled-together directory, I just manually placed the .pem file in the folder I would zip. Now, "sam build" creates a fresh file system to deploy each time and my attempts to place the .pem file in different locations just end up with a deletion or a non-inclusion. Here is my best attempt at showing the current file structure:

- sam-app

  - .aws-sam

    - build

      - LambdaPOCv3

        - app.js
        - template.yaml
    - build.toml
  - events

    - event.json
  - LambdaPOCv3

    - tests

      - unit

        - test-handler.test.ts
    - .eslintignore
    - .eslintrc.js
    - .npmignore
    - .prettierrc.js
    - app.ts
    - jest.config.ts
    - package.json
    - tsconfig.json
  - .gitignore
  - package-lock.json
  - package.json
  - README.md
  - samconfig.toml
  - template.yaml

Any insight on how to configure the build so it's included, or a workaround to not having a .pem file would be great. Thanks!

EDIT: I have found that if I place the .pem file in the build/LambdaPOCv3 folder after running "sam build", it works. However, I am sure this is not the correct way to do this (as I would have to do it every time I built the lambda)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best to create a Lambda layer that includes the certificate (or other reusable dependencies).
See [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/docdb-rest) and [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-documentdb-samples/tree/master/lambda-layers) how you can achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for the tip I will definitely do that next time! My workaround was to just write a script to run sam build and place the .pem folder where it belonged with a single command.